# Default Stereo Camera Separation and Convergence Distance of Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, stereo-3d

For my research, I need to find out what the default values are for stereo camera separation and stereo camera convergence distance in Unity 2020, when I use VR with HTC Vive. And also what metric values they correspond to.
Anyone knows?

And do they differ for other headsets?